# How to query an API with graphql requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

Currently I am using Postman with POST and GRAPHQL type queries.

I wish I could query the API with spring-boot.

First, I want to make it very, very simple to check that everything is working. I tried with httpURLConnection but no luck.
Could you advise me to do something quick?

Then use spring boot, what do you advise me to use?

Thanking you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using some graphql client package instead of writing your own solution. You could use https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android which is suitable for any Java application. More info can be found here: https://apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started-java

Comment: Thanks a lot, using HttpURLConnection I wrote my request wrong so I had a problem. ok for that it's good. However with spring-boot, I want to USE an api and not create an api with the spring-boot application ....

Comment: I see, I've edited original answer, hope that will help.

Comment: ok thank you yes the API I use is obviously apollo compatible. However little question, with spring-boot and jackson, it is possible to create 1 model with annotation and when a request the java objects are created automatically. Do you know if this is also possible with apollo? (I'm going to watch) thank you infinitely

Comment: no problem :) I'm not sure what you actually meant, but I'm guessing that you're talking about automatically picking up schema file and using it with your client package. In that case this would help: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/tutorial/02-add-the-graphql-schema/#download-your-servers-schema

Comment: I'm talking about this: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations .Maybe it's the same principle as your url with the diagram. In fact my basic question is: the API returns me information, how to rebuild in spring boot the objects without doing .set as soon as the API answers me

Comment: I think I can ask my question in this sense: How to serialize java objects (spring-boot) according to the response of the API, without going back manually with the setters

Comment: In that case I think you're looking for this: https://github.com/graphql-java-generator/graphql-maven-plugin-project

Comment: Oula I have a lot of reading suddenly. I did watch this, anyway thank you very much !!!